# How to make a collection view scroll only in one direction using storyboard?

Tags: swift, swiftui, storyboard

i am trying to implement a collection view which contains details of some sort of applications

i want when use scroll for next application it swipes and user unable to see it by swipe back

please give answer which can applicable using both storyboard and swift